# What is the overhead of Rust's Option type?

Tags: performance, rust, null-pointer

In Rust, references can never be null, so in case where you actually need null, such as a linked list, you use the `Option` type:

```
struct Element {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Element>>,
}
```

How much overhead is involved in this in terms of memory allocation and steps to dereference compared to a simple pointer? Is there some "magic" in the compiler/runtime to make `Option` cost-free, or less costly than if one were to implement `Option` by oneself in a non-core library using the same `enum` construct, or by wrapping the pointer in a vector?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Yes, there is some compiler magic that optimises `Option<ptr>` to a single pointer (most of the time).

```
use std::mem::size_of;

macro_rules! show_size {
    (header) => (
        println!("{:<22} {:>4}    {}", "Type", "T", "Option<T>");
    );
    ($t:ty) => (
        println!("{:<22} {:4} {:4}", stringify!($t), size_of::<$t>(), size_of::<Option<$t>>())
    )
}

fn main() {
    show_size!(header);
    show_size!(i32);
    show_size!(&i32);
    show_size!(Box<i32>);
    show_size!(&[i32]);
    show_size!(Vec<i32>);
    show_size!(Result<(), Box<i32>>);
}
```

The following sizes are printed (on a 64-bit machine, so pointers are 8 bytes):

```
// As of Rust 1.22.1
Type                      T    Option<T>
i32                       4    8
&i32                      8    8
Box<i32>                  8    8
&[i32]                   16   16
Vec<i32>                 24   24
Result<(), Box<i32>>      8   16
```

Note that `&i32`, `Box`, `&[i32]`, `Vec<i32>` all use the non-nullable pointer optimization inside an `Option`!

Comment: Furthermore, this optimization occurs in all "`Option`-like" enums, so it will also work for a user-defined `Option`.

Comment: Also note that this optimization can not be stacked. This can be seen in the last line in the example. As you specify the type for Ok as (), that specific result type becomes an "option like enum" and can therefore not be optimized at the option level. But if you try with `Result<i32, i32>` you can see that the optimization is applied again.

Comment: @Pajn It looks like, at least as of March 2020, [this type of optimization *can* be stacked](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0eef41a53fd8081b2f22eb7a54491004) as long as there are enough otherwise invalid binary representations. Of course, non-nullable pointers typically only have one invalid binary representation.