# Reorganize boxed elements inside struct

Tags: data-structures, struct, tree, rust

I'm trying to implement the rotation code for a balanced (AVL) version of a binary search tree in Rust, but I'm having trouble claiming ownership of the nodes to be reorganized.

My structure:

```
struct Tree<T> {
    root: Box<TreeNode<T>>,
    depth: usize,
}

enum TreeNode<T> {
    Empty,
    Node {
        val: T,
        left: Tree<T>,
        right: Tree<T>,
    },
}
```

I know I could use only one type, or `Option`s. This seemed a little nicer.

When I want to implement the rotation:

```
T1, T2, T3 and T4 are subtrees.
         z                                      y 
        / \                                   /   \
       y   T4      Right Rotate (z)          x      z
      / \          - - - - - - - - ->      /  \    /  \ 
     x   T3                               T1  T2  T3  T4
    / \
  T1   T2
```

I cannot find a way to reassign the nodes. I have a `rotate(&mut self, ...)` method that I call on `z` node (the `Tree<T>` node), but I need to use a `match *self.root {}` to cast the root `TreeNode` to its `Node` version to get the components. That works, but I cannot use those extracted values to create a new node.

If I try this:

```
fn insert(&mut self, ...) {
   ...
   // need to rotate
   rotate(self, ...);
}

fn rotate(&mut ztree, ...) {
    ztree.root = match *ztree.root {
        // just re assign same tree to test...
        TreeNode::Node {val, left, right} =>
                Box::new(TreeNode::Node {val: val, left: left, right: right}),
        _ => panic!("meh"),
    } ...
```

I get this error.

```
    |
171 |             ztree.root = match *ztree.root {
    |                                 ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
172 |                 TreeNode::Node {val, left, right} =>
    |                                 ---  ----  ----- ...and here (use `ref right` or `ref mut right`)
    |                                 |    |
    |                                 |    ...and here (use `ref left` or `ref mut left`)
    |                                 hint: to prevent move, use `ref val` or `ref mut val`
```

I understand that it doesn't like me to get ownership on the boxed `TreeNode`, but I don't know how to tell Rust that I'm going to assign a new boxed `TreeNode` and the old `TreeNode` could be claimed locally.

If I try `self.root = Box::new(TreeNode::Empty)` that works just fine, because it knows that I'm reassigning `self.root` to a new box, and previous box and referenced heap struct should be deallocated.

Comment: Take a look at this code: [Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6ef6b2355f5b12146f1232ac7ab72096&version=stable&backtrace=0). Maybe you'll find it useful for your case.

Comment: I see, @red75prime, you are using Option and take to detach the values. That's perfect I totally overlooked that. I think that would work! My branching is different: instead of having options for left/right I have Empty node and "valued" Node. But I could use the Option nevertheless, to be able to take the value and place it somewhere else.
Thanks a lot, consider creating an answer with that, I would totally accept it.

Comment: Also as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504643/what-is-the-overhead-of-rusts-option-type Option doesn't add extra size to pointers, so Option<Box<T>> is as small as Box<T>. Not an extra thing at all. Good to know! That way I can use Option<Box<T>> whenever I need a "typical" pointer, and I'll be able to take the value and move it around.

Comment: Alternatively in my code, I could add a `take`-like method to return the val,left,right values and converting itself to None. That would work too. I think I'll implement that just to confirm that... then go for the standard Option way.

Comment: It's important to note that there's nothing magical about `Option`. The optimization of not adding extra size to pointers (AFAIK) applies to other enums of equivalent layout as well. Likewise, the `take` method can be [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#722) using safe code.

Comment: I just read the code and mimicked it in my TreeNode struct. I didn't know about mem::replace(...). Now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that Rust *did* trust you to replace the value of `ztree.root`. Then you could write

```
fn rotate(&mut ztree, ...) {
    let locally_owned = ztree.root (and I promise to give it back);
    // Now, ztree.root is in some undefined state. 
    // Thats OK though, because I promise to fix it before anyone looks!

    let local_new_value = match locally_owned {
        // just re assign same tree to test...
        TreeNode::Node {val, left, right} =>
                Box::new(TreeNode::Node {val: val, left: left, right: right}),
        // Looks safe-ish, because the whole program will crash, 
        // so the programmer might expect that no one
        // will see the undefined value of ztree.root
        // (in fact, there would be problems when the destructor
        //  of ztree.root is called in the panic)
        _ => panic!("meh"), 
    }
    // FIXED IT! Put a value back into ztree.root
    ztree.root = local_new_value;
}
```

which looks kind of OK. However, imagine if you replaced the `panic("meh")` with some return statement. Then you could have code like this:

```
ztree.root = Box::new(TreeNode::Empty);
// Returns without replacing the value of ztree.root
// because ztree.root is Empty 
rotate(&mut ztree); 
// Now ztree.root is in a undefined state
rotate(&mut ztree); // So something bad happens here
```

Basically, the compiler would have to convince itself that, not only do you intend to replace the value of `ztree.root`, but that there is no code path that would result in the value not being replaced. This is way to complicated, and for this reason, there isn't a way to tell the compiler to let you do what you are trying to do.

Instead, you can solve your problem by restating it. Instead of trying to calculate a new value to replace the old value, you really just need to change the current value, without replacing it. One way to do this is by using [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) like so ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8c17f10249da2d733744dfc0faeb08f3&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn rotate<T>(ztree: &mut Tree<T>) {
    let ref mut root : TreeNode<T> = *ztree.root;

    match root {
        &mut TreeNode::Node {ref mut left, ref mut right, ..} => {
            std::mem::swap(left, right);
        },
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

If you're wondering why `let ref mut root: TreeNode<T> = *ztree.root;` works but `match *ztree.root {...}` doesn't, I am not really sure, but it probably has to do with [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37949).

Comment: Got it! I understood what I was doing wrong... I didn't know how to reconcile matching/borrowing the Node to read its values... with the fact of replacing it later. The comments below the question hinted me: I should either use `Option<T>` and `take()` its value (so it's mine and `Option` gets empty) or, for fun and learning purposes, I could implement the same take() for my TreeNode structure. It needs to use the `mem::replace` which is exactly the `swap` you propose but returning the value. I didn't know that function neither I realized it's perfectly safe and sound to use.