# What is the most memory-efficient array of nullable vectors when most of the second dimension will be empty?

Tags: memory, rust

I have a large fixed-size array of variable-sized arrays of `u32`. Most of the second dimension arrays will be empty (i.e. the first array will be sparsely populated). I think `Vec` is the most suitable type for both dimensions (`Vec<Vec<u32>>`). Because my first array might be quite large, I want to find the most space-efficient way to represent this.

I see two options:

1. I could use a `Vec<Option<Vec<u32>>>`. I'm guessing that as `Option` is a tagged union, this would result each cell being `sizeof(Vec<u32>)` rounded up to the next word boundary for the tag.
2. I could directly use `Vec::with_capacity(0)` for all cells. Does an empty `Vec` allocate zero heap until it's used?

Which is the most space-efficient method?

Comment: *I'm guessing that ...* — Why not just use [`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) to find out what the size is?

Comment: Thanks! Given that I'm very new to the language, I'd still appreciate confirmation that joins the dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, both `Vec<Vec<T>>` and `Vec<Option<Vec<T>>>` have the same space efficiency.

[A `Vec` contains a pointer that will never be null](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees), so the compiler is smart enough to recognize that in the case of `Option<Vec<T>>`, it can represent `None` by putting 0 in the pointer field. [What is the overhead of Rust's Option type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504643/what-is-the-overhead-of-rusts-option-type) contains more information.

What about the backing storage the pointer points to? [A `Vec` doesn't allocate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees) (same link as the first) when you create it with `Vec::new` or `Vec::with_capacity(0)`; in that case, it uses a special, non-null "empty pointer". `Vec` only allocates space on the heap when you `push` something or otherwise force it to allocate. Therefore, the space used both for the `Vec` itself and for its backing storage are the same.

Answer (score 2):

`Vec<Vec<T>>` is a decent starting point. Each entry costs 3 pointers, even if it is empty, and for filled entries there can be additional per-allocation overhead. But depending on which trade-offs you're willing to make, there might be a better solution.

- `Vec<Box<[T]>>` This reduces the size of an entry from 3 pointers to 2 pointers. The downside is that changing the number of elements in a box is both inconvenient (convert to and from `Vec<T>`) and more expensive (reallocation).
- `HashMap<usize, Vec<T>>` This saves a lot of memory if the outer collection is sufficiently sparse. The downsides are higher access cost (hashing, scanning) and a higher per element memory overhead.
- If the collection is only filled once and you never resize the inner collections you could use a split data structure:

  This not only reduces the per-entry size to 1 pointer, it also eliminates the per-allocation overhead.

  ```
  struct Nested<T> {
     data: Vec<T>,
     indices: Vec<usize>,// points after the last element of the i-th slice
  }

  impl<T> Nested<T> {
      fn get_range(&self, i: usize) -> std::ops::Range<usize> {
         assert!(i < self.indices.len());
         if i > 0 {
             self.indices[i-1]..self.indices[i]
          } else {
             0..self.indices[i]
          }
      }

      pub fn get(&self, i:usize) -> &[T] {
          let range = self.get_range(i);
          &self.data[range]
      }

      pub fn get_mut(&mut self, i:usize) -> &mut [T] {
          let range = self.get_range(i);
          &mut self.data[range]
      }
  }
  ```

  For additional memory savings you can reduce the indices to `u32` limiting you to 4 billion elements per collection.

Comment: Good ideas for taking advantage of the sparseness! I especially like the third option. I suspect `BTreeMap` may be a better choice than `HashMap` for the second one, especially if in-order traversal is ever required.