# Does array of Option takes up memory in Rust when Option is None?

Tags: c++, arrays, rust

Firstly, I'm going to publish some similar questions but which are not the same (despite having a similar title and subject), if you find the answer to my question in another post, please notify me in the comments, I really couldn't find it.

| Question | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| [Use `Option` to maybe allocate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76838999/use-option-to-maybe-allocate) | Although I understand that Option does not occupy the total space of Algo until there is Some, I am referring to an array of Option elements that will most likely be allocated on the Heap instead of a simple Option |
| https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876592/what-is-the-most-memory-efficient-array-of-nullable-vectors-when-most-of-the-sec | He is making reference to a type of dynamic allocation, which is vec, so, despite the author asking about the efficiency of Option<> (which according to the answer is the same), it is not the same as my question that makes reference to an array of fixed type and size and not a dynamic data type |
| https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656387/initialize-a-large-fixed-size-array-with-non-copy-types | He is asking about how to initialize with None, but unfortunately it didn't help to know whether the None inside the array (which is a data type of fixed size and type) will occupy additional size in memory or not. |

#### The question

Consider the following code below

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_array: [Option<MyStruct>; 5] = [
        Some(MyStruct{ field1: 1, field2: 2, field3: 3 }),
        Some(MyStruct{ field1: 1, field2: 2, field3: 3 }),
        None,
        Some(MyStruct{ field1: 1, field2: 2, field3: 3 }),
        None,
    ];
}

struct MyStruct {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
    field3: i32,
}
```

Taking into account using an array of type `Option<MyStruct>` with size set to 5, will it occupy the 12 bytes + the option enum flag even when the element at index position 2 of the array is **None**?

Or it will allocate the 12 bytes when the element at index 2 position of the array is `Some(MyStruct)`

If the Rust compiler is not efficient enough for this, what is the equivalent of the following in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Example {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(){
    Example* examples[5];

    /*Initialize examples at position 2*/
    examples[2] = new Example;
    
    return 0;
}
```

In other words, notice that C++ stored a pointer, that is, it did not need to store 12 bytes (three integers) of the structure `Example`

Comment: You store a pointer in C++, and not in Rust, simply because you told C++ to store a pointer (the type is `Example* examples[5]`) but not Rust (`my_array: [Option<MyStruct>; 5]`).

Comment: @jthulhu I certainly know that there are no pointers in Rust, I asked the equivalent in order to occupy the same amount of memory, as was answered in the answer by Silvio Mayolo

Comment: Note that even without pointers, the equivalent of the C++ code is `Option<[MyStruct; 5]>` (which occupies less space) and not `[Option<MyStruct>; 5]`, since only the whole array can be null, not each element separately.

Comment: Also note that unless there are many instances of this type on a data structure, **and** most of them are `None`, it will be more performant to store `Option<[MyStruct; 5]>` and not `Option<Box<[MyStruct; 5]>>` because of the heap allocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Box<T>` is a non-nullable pointer in Rust. An `Option<T>` is either a `None` or a `Some(T)`, but `Option<T>` (as noted in the related answers you link) always allocates enough space for `T`. So in your example, there's no pointer indirection, and every element of `my_array` takes up `size_of<MyStruct>()` space in bytes.

But we can put the two puzzle pieces together. An `Option<Box<T>>` is a potentially-nullable pointer to a `T`. The size of a `Box<T>` is just the size of a pointer, so whether or not the value is there, the `Option<Box<T>>` only needs one pointer's worth of space in automatic memory. The dynamic storage of the value pointed to is only allocated if needed, just like in C++. And Rust even has a [specific optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557608/what-is-the-null-pointer-optimization-in-rust) to ensure that `Option<Box<T>>` works just like a `T*` under the hood. That is, in this particular case, we don't even need to store the "is `Option` empty" discriminator, since we can just use the otherwise-unused `nullptr` value for the underlying pointer to represent that.

So you want an array of `Option<Box<T>>` whose values are all initially `None`. Then you can set some of them to `Some(Box::new(whatever))` and get the allocation when you need it.