# When should I use direct access into a Rust Vec instead of the get method?

Tags: rust

Rust supports two methods for accessing the elements of a vector:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];

let first_element = &v[0];

let second_element = v.get(1);
```

The `get()` method returns an Option type, which seems like a useful safety feature. The C-like syntax `&v[0]` seems shorter to type, but gives up the safety benefits, since invalid reads cause a run-time error rather than producing an indication that the read was out of bounds.

It's not clear to me when I would want to use the direct access approach, because it seems like the only advantage is that it's quicker to type (I save 3 characters). Is there some other advantage (perhaps a speedup?) that I'm not seeing? I guess I would save the conditional of a match expression, but that doesn't seem like it offers much benefit compared to the costs.

Comment: AFAIK, none of them is quicker: the bracket syntax performs also bound-checks (that's why it panics and does not segfault if you are out of bounds).

Comment: @Boiethios Don't I still save on the cost of unpacking the Option though (i.e. a match)? I don't think that's a big savings, but it's not _quite_ identical.

Comment: Not sure if I'm right, but there is no overhead with `Option`: you can see it as a C raw pointer: `None` is `NULL` and `Some` is the ok pointer value.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504643/what-is-the-overhead-of-rusts-option-type

Comment: As a rule of thumb I'd say if you don't expect out of bounds access (i.e. it indicates a programming error or another serious problem with your code) it's fine to stop execution by panic in the index operator. If you expect out of bounds access during normal execution (e.g. it depends on external input) you will want to catch this situation and use `.get` instead.

Comment: @Boiethios That is only if you also use a pointer to the object in C, as you directly get to the object in C, yes Option add an overhead.

Comment: @Stargateur Nope, read the answer I linked.

Comment: @Boiethios I know option don't add size for pointer but that wasn't my point, I'm talking about runtime overhead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Neither of them is quicker because they both do bounds checks. In fact, your question is quite generic because there are other pairs of methods where one of them panics while the other returns an option, such as  [`String::reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.reserve) vs [`String::try_reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.try_reserve).

- If you are sure that you are in bounds, use the brackets version. This is only a syntactic shortcut for `get().unwrap()`.
- If you are unsure of this, use the `get()` method and do your check.
- If you critically need maximum speed **and** you cannot use an iterator **and** you have determined through benchmarks that the indexing is the bottleneck **and** you are sure to be in bounds, you can use the `get_unchecked()` method. Be careful about this because it is `unsafe`: it is always better to not have any `unsafe` block in your code.

---

Just a little bit of advice: if you are concerned by your program performance, avoid using those methods and prefer to use iterators as much as you can. For example, the second example is faster than the first one because in the first case there are one million bounds checks:

```
let v: Vec<_> = (0..1000_000).collect();

for idx in 0..1000_000 {
    // do something with v[idx]
}

for num in &v {
    // do something with num
}
```

Comment: I think `get` is a bit slower. Had couple benchmark that showed the difference in perf. Not remarkable tho

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran Was is in release (`--release` flag)?

Comment: Nope I dont think so

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran Well, every performance related test must be done in release. The dev build doesn't guarantee any optimization, and it's not done to be deployed on prod.

Comment: I don't understand how the `for...in` loop doesn't do bound checks. It doesn't magically know when to end. It has to check on each increment of the iterator if it is at the end of the vec.

Comment: @ErikBongers That's not what “no bound checks” means. It means that it doesn't have to check for each access if it's in-bounds or not, it just loops over the integers range and offset the pointer to return the data. If you call `get(i)`, it loops over the range, but it also verifies at each `get` call that `i` is in bounds.

Comment: Ah, ok, in the 1st example there's 2 checks.

Comment: It seems that `get(n).unwrap()` returns `&T`, bracket indexing returns `T`, if `T` is a `Copy`. I saw it when using `[i32;3]`;