# Memory layout of Option<Box<T>> vs Box<Option<T>>. Which one is better?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have these two structs

```
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Box<Option<Node<T>>>
}

struct Node2<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node2<T>>>
}
```

What's the difference in memory layout? Which one is better?

Comment: TLDR: that's the same thing. `next` is converted to a pointer to `Node`: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d41d7d3ecea770280f3fadc2da0f170a

Comment: There are certainly differences between the two definitions. Differences which I argue are not explicitly covered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504643/what-is-the-overhead-of-rusts-option-type . (For example, there are clear reasons to prefer `Node2` (the one that does `Option<Box<...>>`), but it is interesting to note that `Option<Node>` is itself smaller than `Option<Node2>`, because the former has a niche to store the discriminant.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It is better to use `Node2` because it avoids a heap allocation in case `next` is `None`.

For further explanation, let's simplify the question to: *Is `Option<Box>` or `Box<Option>` better?*

The first thing to note is that both variants only store one pointer:

```rust
type VoidPtr = *const ();
let pointer_size = mem::size_of::<VoidPtr>();
assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<Option<Box<i32>>>(), pointer_size);
assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<Box<Option<i32>>>(), pointer_size);
```

This is not very surprising for `Box<Option>`, since it actually is a pointer to an `Option`. But the disadvantage of using `Box<Option>` is that even if the value is `None`, the Box makes a heap allocation.

```
// Although the Option is None, the pointer is not null,
// so a heap allocation is done to store None.
let none_box_option: Box<Option<i32>> = Box::new(None);
let pointer = &*none_box_option as *const Option<i32>;
assert!(pointer.is_null().not());
```

However, it might be surprising that `Option<Box>` also just uses one pointer instead of, for example, a pointer plus a boolean indicating whether the contained value is `Some` or `None`.
The trick used here (at least in release mode) is called [null pointer optimization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html#representation). A null pointer is used to indicate `None`. Every other value is a `Some` at the specified memory address. This leads to not having to make a heap allocation in case the value is None. Instead, the pointer will be set to null.

```
// A Option<Box> indicates None through a null pointer.
let none_option_box: Option<Box<i32>> = None;
assert!(as_bytes(&none_option_box).iter().all(|&byte| byte == 0));

// A Some Option<Box> simply holds the pointer to the inner value.
let some_option_box: Option<Box<i32>> = Some(Box::new(42));
let inner_bytes = as_bytes(&some_option_box);
let pointer = some_option_box.as_ref().unwrap().as_ref() as *const i32;
let pointer_bytes = as_bytes(&pointer);
assert_eq!(inner_bytes, pointer_bytes);
```

To get back to the original question: The observed behavior transfers to `Node` and `Node2`. Both need the same amount of memory.

```rust
assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<Node<()>>(), mem::size_of::<Node2<()>>());
assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<Node<u64>>(), mem::size_of::<Node2<u64>>());
assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<Node<String>>(), mem::size_of::<Node2<String>>());
```

However, if `next` is `None`, then `Node` will make a heap allocation and `Node2` does not. Therefore I would advise using `Node2`.

---

[Full code example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=c6ea0d8dc8b3f4e8f02d7a7ee43f9b74)