# Why does std::optional not use a sentinel value to represent an empty optional?

Tags: c++, language-design, stdoptional

I know this ship has sailed due to ABI breakage it would require, but I wonder why originally implementations did not decide to use some magic bit pattern for `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc... to signal empty optional value. This obviously requires some "free" value in the bit representation of the type, so for example it would not work for `int`, `size_t` but many complex types have certain representations that can never occur for valid instance.

C++ could even specify some way to opt in for your type, e.g. by specializing

```
std::nullopt_sentinel
```

for user defined types.

My best guess is that complexity of specifying/implementing this(because you would need to implement sentinels for many many types in `std::`) was much greater than just using a bool always, but I wonder if there are other reasons.

Similar answer for Rust that seems to implement this sometimes

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16515488/700825

Comment: what would a "free" not used value/bit pattern for `std::vector` or `std::string` be?

Comment: @bolov for `std::string`, there are a number of possible bit patterns based on small string optimization. You could put a specific byte past the the null-terminator for a string contained within `std::optional`. For `std::vector`, you could use a size that is greater than the capacity, or some other nonsensical state.

Comment: That would force the user code to check for the extra invalid state, wherever they had to check for empty state. The difference between  invalid and empty would become a source of confusion, resulting in spread of bad-practice. One extra system word for types with dynamic allocation is not a major concern. If the library author knows of a certain impossible bit-pattern for a type, strict aliasing rule is an impediment to implementing such optimization for `std::optional`.

Comment: "*for example it would not work for `int`, `size_t`*" You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: This looks like an outright defect/missed opportunity, nothing more.

Comment: @Red.Wave no, it would not require an additional test. Checking `std::optional::empty()` would simply check if the stored `std::string` is in an invalid state. You would merely replace one test with another. `operator*` would still be UB for such a state, and I don't see how a change in the implementation details of `std::optional` somehow results in "bad practice" on the user's end. Strict aliasing doesn't seem related, since you're not aliasing anything. Such a `std::optional` specialization would simply store `std::string` as a data member.

Comment: @JanSchultke if the invalid test is part of class API for any STL class, then it will promote bad-practice - due to confusion between empty and invalid. Otherwise - in the absence such API - `optional` will be defined through alaising, in order to ensure to not introduce memory overhead, and violation happens. Th 3rd option would be to keep the `invalid` API private to the library, so it can be used in `optional` but not user code; this will break ABI. So you need to copy the source for all such types into another namespace and aquire the change.

Comment: @Red.Wave the interface of `std::optional` would be identical, no matter whether it stores a potentially invalid `std::string` under the hood, or a `bool` and an always valid `std::string`. It's also not clear whether aliasing would be allowed or desirable in this case, and it's also not clear why you think that this is an issue which must be user-facing. I think you misunderstand what is being proposed and discussed here. If there was a customization point, it could be via specializing a `std::invalid_for_optional` class template with a call operator. This can all be neatly hidden away.

Comment: No! I perfectly understand it. I guess you don't quite grasp my point. The point is simple: `std::vector` should not have a public `invalid` member function. If it lacks a private `invalid` member function too, the kind of optimization you need is not safely achievable. That member function must be exclusively accessible by `optional`.

Comment: What actual problem would it solve, in oppose to existing implementation?

Comment: @Red.Wave why do you think it needs to be a member function named `invalid`? You can achieve all this with no changes to the interface of `std::vector` or `std::string`, and I think you're missing that point. The standard library can also partially specialize `std::optional` for any library types it wants; there are zero prerequisites to this. It's all an implementation detail. There doesn't need to be anything user-facing, although the option for customization seems useful.

Comment: @JanSchultke how do you plan on accessing the internals of a class without an inteface function? All the data members of STL classes are private - as good practice demands. So, how do you plan on detecting the validity of their state? I don't insist on specific names, but what would be the name of a function that tests validity?

Comment: @Red.Wave `std::string` could simply declare `std::optional` as a `friend`.

Comment: That's implementation detail. Can this design scale? What if someone comes up with ideas for `std::variant` or `std::expected`? Whatever the case, std doesn't discuss implementation details; It rather specifies compile-time and runtime constraints and conditions. If you already have a working implementation, you can propose it to BOOST.

Comment: This idea was proposed.  But it was rejected, since it breaks class invariants.  The language lacked the terminology and rules to allow "a std::string with a bit pattern that is not possible in a std::string"

Comment: @DrewDormann do you have some wg21 link, I have a feeling your comment is a proper answer, but could not google anything about what you mentioned.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The idea may have died before it became a paper.  [There is some discussion about it here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/fghaQHk8oe8?pli=1).  I do not wish to cite that discussion in an answer, as it closely involves a name that has been considered very toxic to the community, regarding women and children.  You or anyone else is welcome to cite that link in a posted answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann thank you for the link

Answer (score 4):

The standard library and any user specializing `std::optional` for their own types are already free to implement it that way for types where it is possible (see [[namespace.std] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2)).

Nothing in the specification of `std::optional` mandates use of a `bool` flag to indicate the presence of a value. How the empty state is identified is an implementation detail. The user of `std::optional` can't rely on observing anything else about the internal state if the optional is empty.

Comment: Are users even allowed to specialize `optional`? That can be brittle, if the standard adds more members to it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: They can specialize it if the type being specialized is not in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Users are allowed to specialize all standard library templates for types dependent on user-defined types as long as the requirements imposed on the standard library implementation are also satisfied by the user specialization and assuming there is no specific exception, which isn't the case for `std::optional`. (see https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If a new standard extends the interface, then, just like the standard library implementation itself, the user has to implement the new interface for their types. The standard library and other users may assume that every specialization fully implements the interface according to the used C++ edition.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But this is not uncommon. `std::numeric_limits`, `std::hash`, etc. are commonly specialized and you would potentially have the same problem there with a new C++ revision.

Comment: @user17732522 Those are traits classes, specializing them is their intended use. And any changes to the standard-mandated contract for them are usually backward-compatible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: And if the standard adds more members to those types (which has happened before), then your code may be broken with the next standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `numeric_limits` had significant interface changes with C++11. But I agree that for certain classes that are more likely to be user-specialized the probably of such changes will be smaller. But it is also certainly intended for users to make use of this permission to optimize implementations for their types, even if it is less common than these two examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that a type can identify that it has this "magic bit pattern" that represents "not a value". And let's say that `optional<T>` will be implemented differently depending on whether `T` advertises this.

So here's a question: is this "magic bit pattern" actually a valid value of type `T`?

If the answer to this question is "yes", then we have a problem. Because it is a valid value of type `T`, a user can create an object of type `T` *with that value*, right? So... what happens if they do `optional<T> t(invalid_value);`? Is `t` considered to be "engaged, but containing a value" or is `t` considered to be an unengaged `optional`?

If it's the former, then how can `optional<T>` recognize the difference between `optional<T> t{}` and `optional<T> t(invalid_value);`? The bit pattern of these two `t`s is *identical*, so they must behave identically, right?

So if it's the latter, then you're telling me that this code:

```
T t = something();
optional<T> ot(t);
if(ot)
{
  //Do something with ot
}
```

It is possible for you to never do something with `ot` based on what `something` returns? That's nonsensical. From the structure of the code, you handed it a `t`, and `optional<T>` is supposed to store a `T` if you give it one. That's what the type is for.

So, going back to the question, now this "magic bit pattern" must be considered to be not a valid value of type `T`. That is, you cannot create a `T` that has this "magic bit pattern."

Now, how do you implement this? When you construct an unengaged `optional<T>`, it has to treat the storage of `T` as being just a bag of bits. It must initialize this bag of bits with a value acquired from some `T`-based interface. And then, to test if the `optional<T>` is engaged, it has to compare all of those bits to the unengaged bits.

This now requires that `T` must not be trivially copyable. Or trivially default constructible. Otherwise, a `T` could be created that has the invalid value.

But more than that, you're missing one of the key reasons to even want this: space efficiency.

See, most of the "many complex types [that] have certain representations that can never occur for valid instance" are types that are substantially bigger than a `bool`. Even a `vector<int>` is 3x the size of a `bool` (including the padding for 64-bit pointers), let alone a `std::string` with small-string optimization. Because most of these types are significantly larger than the tracking data used to represent them, the space efficiency argument isn't particularly convincing.

Most of the cases where you want this space efficiency are things like non-nullable pointers or enumerators. That is, you want a null pointer value to act like an unengaged `optional<T*>`, and you want an enumeration value that isn't one of the enumerators to act like an unengaged `optional<E>`. These are small types, comparable to the size of `bool`, so the current `optional` implementation would double their size. The space savings is significant.

The larger the `T`, the less meaningful the space savings is.

But you'll notice one other thing. The larger the `T` is, the *longer it takes* to test if `optional<T>` is unengaged. If `T` is 24 bytes in size, you have to compare 3 8-byte words to see if it is engaged.

Again, doing this only makes sense if `T` is *small*. The bigger the `T`, the worse it gets.